# How to access a specific list of fields from a model object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below Stream class that is getting returned from DB:

```
Stream<Transaction> transctions=transRepository.findByTransctionId();

public class Transaction{

String  transctionId;
String accountId;
String transName;
String accountName;

}
```

Now my Requirement is as below:
Transaction entity  has 4 fields. So, from DB all the 4 fields were fetched by Jpa.

But client who needs this data ,he has sent the columnsName in list that  he is looking from Transaction model

```
List<String> columnNames=Arrays.asList("transctionId","accountName")
```

I have post this data to Kafka.I have to take each Transction from this stream post it to kafka.

But  cline is looking for only this 2 fields "transctionId","accountName" should go as part of Transaction in Kafka instead of all 4 fields.

```
The data should go in form of json to Kafa having below format:
{

 "transctionId":"1234",
 "accountName" :"test-account"
}
```

Basically only those fields should go to kafka which they have asked for instead of converting the whole pojo to json and send it.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You can write custom SQL query in repository, and fetch only required columns. Then your return type will be `List<Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: Hi @Jignesh,In my case that is not possible as  my table is having 50 + column and cline can send any thing out of this 50 column based on their choice for different request. and we are using JDBC template approach where we are generting custom sql.But the names client is sending is not exact match of DB column name.So,how can i do that ..any suggestion.

Comment: Can you show the code of how you are fetching the data from database? I mean your repository code.

Comment: You may apply a TransactionDTO object, map from Transaction to TransactionDTO and then put TransactionDTO into Kafka. That is all DTOs is about https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you need to invoke a method, but you only have its name, the only way I know is via reflection. I would do it like this:

```
Stream<Transaction> transctions=transRepository.findByTransctionId();
List<Transaction> outTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
transactions.forEach(tr -> {
    Transaction outTransaction = new Transaction();
    columnNames.forEach( col -> {
        try {
            var getMethod = tr.getClass().getMethod("get" + StringUtils.capitalize(col));
            Object value = getMethod.invoke(tr);
            String valueStr = value instanceof String ? value.toString() : "";
            var setMethod = outTransaction.getClass().getMethod("set" + StringUtils.capitalize(col));
            setMethod.invoke(outTransaction, valueStr);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    outTransactions.add(outTransaction);
});
```

There is a lot of traversing, but with the requirements you have, this is the generic solution I can come up with. Another shortcoming to this solution is the creation of new Transaction objects. Which means that if Transactions are many, memory usage can grow. Maybe this solution can be optimised to take advantage of streaming the transactions from the DB.

Another way to do it is to have different endpoints for each known set of properties that the client sends you. For example:

```
@GetMapping("/transaction_id_and_name")
List<Transaction> getTransactionsIdAndName() {
   ... obtain Transactions, return a new list of Transactions, with transaction_id and name ... }

@GetMapping("/transaction_id_and_status")
List<Transaction> getTransactionsNameAndStatus() {...}
```